# NextJs: 404 page back button returns back to 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a condition inside my lifecycle method of **user** Page such that if the user enters an URL with certain parameters such as `somePage.com/user/1` will fetch the data of the user with ID 1, however, if the user enters the URL as  `somePage.com/user/1ABC` then im routing them to a custom 404 page. My issue is when im in the 404-page clicking on the back button will take me back to the page with URL `somePage.com/user/1ABC` and then will route back to the same 404-page as the URL param met a condition in the lifecycle method of the user page.

I would like to route the user to some other URL if they land up in the 404-page and click on the back button of the browser.

Comment: Need to see at least some code. What other URL do you want it to route you? Is it a static URL for anyone to be routed to upon 404 page visit? Or will it be dynamically determined, for example last successful page landing?

Comment: I was using Router.push to redirect to the 404 page in the User page, changed it to Router.replace and now the back button goes back to the last successful page.

Comment: You can handle it in the page itself by having a back Link! The next link knows the routing history and can redirect you back!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Router.push will add the new URL into the history stack, however, Router.replace will redirect to the 404-page without adding a new URL entry into the history stack. So the back button will redirect to the last successful entry in the history stack, https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreplace gives a clear example.