# nextjs get back to page before 404 from page after 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have created a 404 page using nextjs which works without any config and show my custom 404 page.
I have a link in this page which redirects user to another page. On this new page if user click `back` I want to send them back to the page before 404.
I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926039/nextjs-404-page-back-button-returns-back-to-404-page) but there is nowhere I used `router.push`.

How can I do this?

`page1>404page>page2`
by clicking back button on page2 I want to go to page1 not 404page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you can use `router.replace`.

According to the docs:

> Similar to the replace prop in next/link, router.replace will prevent adding a new URL entry into the history stack.

To actually get (and use) the router object, you might use the `useRouter` object provided with NextJS. Hence, your 404 page might look like this:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>404</h3>
      <h2>
        Try go here instead:{" "}
        <span onClick={() => router.replace("/page2")}>Go page2</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This way, by going to page2, you replace the 404 entry in the history stack by the page2 url which gives the behavior you expect ([working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-frog-lse7f?file=/pages/404.js))